# Merge object arrays with child object arrays inside

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have two arrays (both `County` and `City` are conformed to `Comparable`):

```
let array1 = [
  Country(code: "US", cities: [
    City(name: "Dallas"),
    City(name: "New York")
  ]),
  Country(code: "UK", cities: [
    City(name: "London"),
    City(name: "Manchester")
  ])
]

let array2 = [
  Country(code: "DE", cities: [
    City(name: "Munich"),
    City(name: "Leipzig")
  ]),
  Country(code: "US", cities: [
    City(name: "Seattle")
    City(name: "New York")
  ]),
  Country(code: "UK", cities: [
    City(name: "London"),
    City(name: "Birmingham"),
    City(name: "Manchester")
  ])
]
```

So far I managed to combine those only comparing country codes:

```
let mergedArray = array1 + array2.filter { country in
  return !array1.contains { $0.code == country.code }
}
```

How do I account for those repeated cities inside? Basically to get this:

```
let mergedArray = [
  Country(code: "DE", cities: [
    City(name: "Munich"),
    City(name: "Leipzig")
  ]),
  Country(code: "US", cities: [
    City(name: "Dallas"),
    City(name: "Seattle")
    City(name: "New York")
  ]),
  Country(code: "UK", cities: [
    City(name: "London"),
    City(name: "Birmingham"),
    City(name: "Manchester")
  ])
]
```

Tried also (isn't adding those extra cities for UK):

```
func combine<T>(_ arrays: Array<T>?...) -> Set<T> {
  return arrays.compactMap{$0}.compactMap{Set($0)}.reduce(Set<T>()){$0.union($1)}
}
```

and tried this but no luck at all (a lot of duplicates):

```
let mergedArray = array1 + array2.filter { country in
  return !array1.contains { $0.code == country.code }  ||
    (!array1.contains(where: { $0.cities?.contains(where: country.cities!.contains) as! Bool }))
}
```

Comment: I would load the first array into a dictionary, keyed by country name. The iterate over your second array. Check if the dictionary has an entry for the country, if not, just add the country to the dictionary. If it does you need to merge the cities. Finally convert the dictionary back to an array. To merge the city arrays you can convert each to a set and the convert the union of the two sets back to an array.

Comment: Do you wanna attempt with as little lines as possible or something? If not, can't you just iterate over `array1` using a `ForEach` and for all countries matching the code inside `array2` just add the city objects into the `Country` object in `array1`. Append all the "non-matching" country codes at the end

Comment: Yeah, good ideas @Paulw11 and @Rikh but I just wanted the cleanest solution if possible. Of course, I can manually go through the arrays and do it with `for` and `if` but that wouldn't be fun :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make `City` conform to `Hashable`? If so, try this:

```
var dict = [String: Set<City>]() // code -> cities

for country in array1 + array2 {
    dict[country.code, default: Set<City>()].formUnion(country.cities)
}

// convert back to array
let mergedArray = dict.map { code, cities in
    Country(code: code, cities: Array(cities))
}
```

Comment: Ah! That's genius :) so basically items in `Set` can't have duplicates so that works perfectly. And 4 lines of code basically! Thanks!